# Batch script to print last line of many files in a folder matching a file name pattern

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have multiple text files in a folder. I would like to print the last line of each file found in the folder matching the file name pattern `*.Config` and redirect those lines to a new text file.

The below script works for 1 text file. But at the moment I do a **for** loop for multiple text files and `%lastline%` prints always the same value.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

for /f %%i in ('dir /b *.Config') do (
    for /r "delims==" %%a in (%%i) do (
        set lastline=%%a
        echo %lastline% is the last line of %%i >> vResult.txt
    ) 
)
```

Comment: There is no need for variable `lastline` when you do `echo %%a`; if you want to use the variable, read it like `!lastline!` to *use* delayed expansion (you only enabled it, but `%lastline%` does not use it). By the way, your code does also not work for the first time. You have to decide whether you want to use [`for /R`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) or [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this batch code to get written into file `vResult.txt` in current directory the last line of each *.config file in current directory:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 
del vResult.txt 2>nul
for %%I in (*.config) do (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%%I") do set "LastLine=%%L"
    echo !LastLine! is the last line of %%I>>vResult.txt
)
endlocal
```

First command extensions as needed for the second **FOR** command line and delayed environment variable expansion as needed for echoing the last line of each file are enabled with second command line. Command extensions are enabled by default, but not delayed expansion.

Then a perhaps already existing `vResult.txt` is deleted with suppressing the error message output by command **DEL** to handle **STDERR** by redirecting it to device **NUL** in case of the file to delete does not exist.

The outer **FOR** searches for `*.config` files in current directory with hidden attribute not set. There is no need to use command **DIR** here except it would be necessary to find also hidden *.config files.

The inner **FOR** processes the lines of each *.config file found by the outer **FOR** loop. It is in general advisable to enclose the file name in double quotes and use `usebackq` to interpret the double quoted file name as file name and not as string to process in case of a *.config file contains a space character. `delims=` disables splitting each line up on spaces/tabs to get entire line.

As the environment variable `LastLine` is defined/modified within a command block, it is necessary to use delayed expansion as enabled at beginning with referencing the environment variable with exclamation marks instead of percent signs.

All environment variables referenced with percent signs of entire command block to execute on each iteration of outer **FOR** are replaced already by Windows command interpreter with current value of referenced environment variable before executing outer **FOR** command. This resulted on your batch code with **ECHO** command line additionally in wrong loop in replacing `%lastline%` by nothing before the outer **FOR** is executed the first time.

For debugging a batch file and to see what Windows command interpreter really executes after preprocessing the command lines and the command blocks, remove or comment out `@echo off` or change that line to `@echo on`, open a command prompt window, and run the batch file from within this console window by entering its name with full path enclosed in double quotes after changing the current directory to the directory on which the batch file should work.

A space character left of redirection operator `>>` is also output by command **ECHO** and therefore also written to the text file as trailing space which is the reason why the space character left of `>>` is removed here. The space character right of `>>` would be ignored, but is here also removed.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `set /?`

And see also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much! It works just fine, exactly what I wanted to achieve!

Comment: Why don't you just redirect the whole outer `for` loop once like `>`? this would avoid having to delete the file `vResult.txt` at the beginning...

Comment: That would be possible, too. But it has a disadvantage which I don't like. If the outer __FOR__ can't find any *.config file in current directory, the file `vResult.txt` is created nevertheless in current directory with 0 bytes. I don't like it creating an output file with 0 bytes when no file could be found to process. A 0 byte file consumes nevertheless a block in file system and causes a useless disk write on SSD disks which could be easily avoided.

Comment: @Mofi, I agree, a zero-byte file is not beautiful; although such do not consume a block on disk, they cause a useless disk write due to update of the file allocation table...

Comment: @aschipfl You are right. On Windows file systems a file with 0 bytes does not consume a block on storage media, just an entry in file allocation table.